# Manejo de etiquetas desde una función fuera de la clase - PyQT

Tags: python, python-3.x

Soy nuevo programando en *Python* y *PyQT*, y espero que puedan ayudarme con un problema que me tiene atascado, y no sé cómo continuar.

Parte del programa que quiero desarrollar, consiste en hacer un ping cada 5 segundos a un servidor, para comprobar que el servidor está operativo.

He creado en *PyQT* una serie de controles, entre las que se encuentran unas etiquetas, que pretenden mostrarme el estado del servidor. Para ello, si el *ping* devuelve respuesta, se muestran unas etiquetas con unas imágenes en verde, y si no hay respuesta, otras en rojo.

En una clase, cargo la ventana que he creado en *PyQT*, y me funciona solo si desde la clase oculto o muestro las etiquetas en función del valor que obtengo del *ping*. Pero el problema que tengo es que necesito hacerlo desde una función fuera de la clase, y no sé cómo hacerlo, ya que me da error con todo lo que he probado.

```
self.EtWifi.hide(), EtWifi.hide(), EstadoWifi.EtWifi.hide()
```

La parte que me falla es la función `EstadoWifi` a partir de querer mostrar u ocultar las etiquetas `self.EtWifi.hide()`.

Código:

```
import subprocess
import os
import sys
import threading
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import ctypes # GetSystemMetr'cs

def EstadoWifi():
    with open(os.devnull, "wb") as Estado:
        ip = "192.168.1.1"
        global WlfiActivo
        result = subprocess.Popen(
            ["ping", "-n", "1", "-w", "2", ip], stdout= Estado, stderr=Estado
        ).wait()

        if result:
            WifiActivo = 0
            self.EtWifi.hide()
            self.EtWifiVerde.hide()
            self.EtWifiRojo.show()

        else:
            WifiActivo = 1
            self.EtWifi.hide()
            self.EtWifiVerde.show()
            self.EtWifiRojo.hide()

class Main(QMainWindow):
    #Método constructor de la dase
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        #Calgar la configuracion del archivo .ui en el objeto
        uic.loadUi("ContadorPiezas.ui", self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Contador de piezas automático")
        self.showMaximized()
        resolucion = ctypes.windll.user32
        resolucion_ancho = resolucion.GetSystemMetrics(0)
        resolucion_alto = resolucion.GetSystemMetrics(1)
        left = (resolucion_ancho / 2) - (self.frameSize().width() / 2)
        top = (resolucion_alto / 2) - (self.frameSize().height() / 2)
        self.move(left, top)
        threading.Timer(5.0, EstadoWifi).start()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
_ventana = Main()
_ventana.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: En lugar de pegar **una imagen** de tu código, sería *mas mejor* que pegaras el código en si; facilita tanto la lectura como las pruebas para otros que intenten ayudarte. Piensa que **no todo el mundo** utiliza un ordenador para acceder.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so] Diego, como te ha comentado Trauma no debes postear tu código usando una imágen ya que complicas la vida a quién quiera ayudarte al intentar reproducir tu código y por otro lado no es bueno para el sitio ya que los buscadores buscan texto, no imágenes. Simplemente copia y pega tu código, lo seleccionas y pulsas  `Ctrl + k` para formatearlo. Por esta vez he usado un OCR y he editado tu pregunta pero procura no repetirlo. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Estas intentando acceder a un atributos de un objeto desde una función externa a la clase propietaria. Cuando en tu función `EstadoWifi` haces algo como `self.EtWifi.hide()` simplemente no sabe a que se está haciendo referencia porque `EtWifi` es un atributo de la clase principal.

Podemos solucionarlo de varias formas:

- Hacer que la función `EstadoWifi` sea un método de la clase:

  ```
  import subprocess
  import os
  import sys
  import threading
  from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
  from PyQt5 import uic
  from PyQt5.QtGui import *
  import ctypes # GetSystemMetr'cs


  class Main(QMainWindow):
      #Método constructor de la dase
      def __init__(self):
          QMainWindow.__init__(self)
          #Calgar la configuracion del archivo .ui en el objeto
          uic.loadUi("ContadorPiezas.ui", self)
          self.setWindowTitle("Contador de piezas automático")
          self.showMaximized()
          resolucion = ctypes.windll.user32
          resolucion_ancho = resolucion.GetSystemMetrics(0)
          resolucion_alto = resolucion.GetSystemMetrics(1)
          left = (resolucion_ancho / 2) - (self.frameSize().width() / 2)
          top = (resolucion_alto / 2) - (self.frameSize().height() / 2)
          self.move(left, top)
          threading.Timer(5.0, self.EstadoWifi).start()

      def EstadoWifi(self):
          with open(os.devnull, "wb") as Estado:
              ip = "192.168.1.1"
              global WlfiActivo
              result = subprocess.Popen(["ping", "-n", "1", "-w", "2", ip], stdout= Estado, stderr=Estado).wait()

              if result:
                  WifiActivo = 0
                  self.EtWifi.hide()
                  self.EtWifiVerde.hide()
                  self.EtWifiRojo.show()

              else:
                  WifiActivo = 1
                  self.EtWifi.hide()
                  self.EtWifiVerde.show()
                  self.EtWifiRojo.hide()
              threading.Timer(5.0, EstadoWifi, args = [self]).start()


  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  _ventana = Main()
  _ventana.show()
  app.exec_()
  ```
- Pasar la instancia de tu clase principal como parámetro a la función `EstadoWifi`:

  ```
  import subprocess
  import os
  import sys
  import threading
  from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
  from PyQt5 import uic
  from PyQt5.QtGui import *
  import ctypes # GetSystemMetr'cs

  def EstadoWifi(root):
      with open(os.devnull, "wb") as Estado:
          ip = "192.168.1.1"
          global WlfiActivo
          result = subprocess.Popen(["ping", "-n", "1", "-w", "2", ip], stdout= Estado, stderr=Estado).wait()

          if result:
              WifiActivo = 0
              root.EtWifi.hide()
              root.EtWifiVerde.hide()
              root.EtWifiRojo.show()

          else:
              WifiActivo = 1
              root.EtWifi.hide()
              root.EtWifiVerde.show()
              root.EtWifiRojo.hide()
          threading.Timer(5.0, EstadoWifi, args = [root]).start()

  class Main(QMainWindow):
      #Método constructor de la dase
      def __init__(self):
          QMainWindow.__init__(self)
          #Calgar la configuracion del archivo .ui en el objeto
          uic.loadUi("ContadorPiezas.ui", self)
          self.setWindowTitle("Contador de piezas automático")
          self.showMaximized()
          resolucion = ctypes.windll.user32
          resolucion_ancho = resolucion.GetSystemMetrics(0)
          resolucion_alto = resolucion.GetSystemMetrics(1)
          left = (resolucion_ancho / 2) - (self.frameSize().width() / 2)
          top = (resolucion_alto / 2) - (self.frameSize().height() / 2)
          self.move(left, top)
          threading.Timer(5.0, EstadoWifi, args = [self]).start()

  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  _ventana = Main()
  _ventana.show()
  app.exec_()
  ```
- De todas formas, esta opciones **NO DEBERIAS USARLAS** ya que los Widgets de Qt **no son thread-safe**. Lo más seguro es usar señales o colas(Queue) para comunicar hilos entre si. El siguiente código comprueba cada 5 segundos si el router está conectado y actualiza las etiquetas de acuerdo a ello usando una señal creada por nosotros. La función se ejecuta en un `QThread`:

  ```
  import subprocess
  import os
  import sys
  from time import sleep
  from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
  from PyQt5 import uic
  from PyQt5.QtGui import *
  import ctypes # GetSystemMetr'cs
  from PyQt5 import QtCore



  class EstadoWifi(QtCore.QThread):
      estado = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)

      def __init__(self):
          QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)

      def run(self):
          with open(os.devnull, "wb") as Estado:
              ip = "192.168.1.1"
              while True:
                  result = subprocess.Popen(["ping", "-n", "1", "-w", "2", ip], stdout= Estado, stderr=Estado).wait()
                  self.estado.emit(result)
                  sleep(5)

  class Main(QMainWindow):
      #Método constructor de la dase
      def __init__(self):
          QMainWindow.__init__(self)
          #Calgar la configuracion del archivo .ui en el objeto
          uic.loadUi("ContadorPiezas.ui", self)
          self.setWindowTitle("Contador de piezas automático")
          self.showMaximized()
          resolucion = ctypes.windll.user32
          resolucion_ancho = resolucion.GetSystemMetrics(0)
          resolucion_alto = resolucion.GetSystemMetrics(1)
          left = (resolucion_ancho / 2) - (self.frameSize().width() / 2)
          top = (resolucion_alto / 2) - (self.frameSize().height() / 2)
          self.move(left, top)
          self.monitor = EstadoWifi()
          self.monitor.estado.connect(self.control_etiquetas)
          self.monitor.start()

      def control_etiquetas(self, estado):
          if estado:
              self.EtWifi.hide()
              self.EtWifiVerde.hide()
              self.EtWifiRojo.show()
          else:
              self.EtWifi.hide()
              self.EtWifiVerde.show()
              self.EtWifiRojo.hide()


  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  _ventana = Main()
  _ventana.show()
  app.exec_()
  ```